# Type checker libraries

Tags: compiler-construction, haskell, typechecking

I'm witting a compiler and I'm searching for a library that could do type checking for me.  So far I didn't find anything useful=/  Does anyone know good type checking libraries?  I'm using Haskell, but I'll consider any other language if the library is good=)

Comment: About 100% of type checking depend on the (implemented) language's type system and the compiler's IR/AST. I don't think you can write a library on this topic...

Comment: You can write a theorem prover, so you can write a type checking library too.  I don't see why it would be impossible.

Comment: What language are you going to be compiling?

Comment: @maarons: Not so much "impossible" as impractical: It would enforce a certain IR format (and/or require you to write a lot of glue code) and it could only cope with whatever kind of type system(s) the library bothers to implement.

Comment: @Will: A typed Lisp dialect, but the type system can be a simple one.

Comment: @delan: I don't think that much of the glue code would be needed.  About the type system - yes that is right and I would be OK with that.

Comment: @maarons: simple as in you just want to have access to primitives, or simple as in you want base types for a higher-level implementation, or ... ?

Comment: @Will: As in I don't much care about type system expressiveness - I'm not constrained by any language standard so I'll consider any type checking library.

Comment: You seriously need to consider typechecking vs. type inference. Typechecking is, frankly, trivial for any language without dependent types. You have your AST, you have a typing environment you build up as you go of what types given identifiers have, and you just *check* that they match as you continue to traverse the AST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be libraries to help with bits of the type checker especially if you do really want a type checker and not type inference. For instance, there have been libraries embedding logic programming in Haskell - at 10,000 feet it seems a good bit easier to write a type checker using logic programming than functional programming (for example Chameleon mentioned by **shapr** above is based on the CHR language embedded in Haskell).

That said, embedded logic programming in Haskell is a big step with probably little documentation if you've never written a type checker before. Similarly attribute grammars (i.e. UUAG) are a pleasant formalism supplying quite a bit of the machinery you would need to write yourself, but they might put you it a place with few signposts if you've never used one previously.

Unless you've written a type checker before, maybe it is better not to worry about libraries and work through the process from scratch. The "Typing Haskell in Haskell" paper by Mark P. Jones is probably as good a start point as any.

Comment: Seems like there are no good ready solutions and I'll have to do it myself.  The paper seems quite helpful, thanks.

Comment: I once asked someone what was their favorite piece of code they had written. He thought for a moment, and then said, "the type checker for (some compiler)." :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Martin Sulzmann's [Chameleon](http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~sulzmann/chameleon/download/haskell.html) would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I found several type checkers on hackage, including [dedukti](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dedukti), [hybrid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hybrid), and [lambdacube](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lambdacube), possibly one of these would work?

Comment: dedukti won't build, and the other two seem dead=/